Load time of package.json?
Working with a node repl and tryihng this:
process.chdri('M://source/MySite')
let queries = await import('./src/graphql/queries.js')

Result is this:
export const getCompanySingleTable = /* GraphQL */ `
^^^^^^

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

In 'M://source/MySite/' there is a package.json that contains the line:
    "type": "module",

I'm guessing the error is occurring because the package.json isn't being read as the closest one.  This raises the question,
When in package.json loaded?
Is it looked for when my repl is started?  Is it looked for when when I try the dynamic import?

I could not reproduce this. What Node version are you using? Are you certain the nearest package.json has its type set to module? Would you be able to create a minimal, reproducible example, verify you have a problem, then share instructions on reproducing it?

I just closed all my windows, restarted and, it worked.  No idea, why it didn't before, but it seems it must be something to do with my environment / context.
